# Import module using relative paths

Tags: python-3.x

Let me start off by saying I know this issue has already been discussed, but I could not find a solution that was similar to my case.

I have a directory structure like the following:

- project/

  - tools

    - my_tool

      - tool_name.py
  - tests

    - lib

      - constants.py
      - my_test.py
      - common/

        - check_lib.py

I need to import constants.py, check_lib.py, and tool_name.py into my_test.py using relative paths. Is there a way to do this even though several of my modules are in various depths within different directories in my project? I am trying to do this directly in the code with a "from module.path import module" type of import. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**MY solution was the following:**

tool_name.py

> print("tool_name.py imported")

constants.py

> print("constants.py imported")

check_lib.py

> print("check_lib.py imported")

my_test.py

> import constants
>   import common.check_lib
>
> import sys
>   import os
>   sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('test_project/tools/my_tool'))
>
> import tool_name

output :

> constants.py imported
>   check_lib.py imported
>   tool_name.py imported
>   my_test.py is running

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tool_name.py

```py
print("tool_name.py imported")
```

constants.py

```py
print("constants.py imported")
```

check_lib.py

```py
print("check_lib.py imported")
```

my_test.py

```py
import constants
import common.check_lib

from sys import path as external_import

external_import.append("../../tools/my_tool/")
import tool_name

print("my_test.py is running")
```

output :

```
constants.py imported
check_lib.py imported
tool_name.py imported
my_test.py is running
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will give this a try tomorrow and report back if this approach works with my scenario otherwise ill clarify my question better. But this seems to be what i was looking for!

Comment: Okay. Be sure that you are placing all the files into right directories.

Comment: I couldn't get it to append the path the exact way you had set it, however, this led me pretty close to the right answer i was looking for so I gave you an upvote. Thank you for your help!

Comment: **../** is used to jump out from current folder. 1st for **lib** 2nd for **tests**. Now we are in our **project** folder. Now we can choose child directory in which we want to deep inside.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PYTHONPATH=.`, go to the directory one level up from "project".

Invoke your code with somewhat long names, e.g. `$ python -m project.tools.my_tool.tool_name`.
That way "tools" code will be allowed to access "tests", since it's still within "project".

Comment: Thank you for the response, I should have mentioned I am trying to do this directly in the code with a "from module.path import module" type of import.